# Yii2 Приоритетная сортировка по нескольким полям

Tags: yii2

Есть таблица Task с полями

- id
- title
- status
- add_date
- info

Поле статус может принимать значения

- new
- comlite
- ready
- draft
- deny

Есть запрос по типу.

```
$query = Task::find()
  ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
  ->all();
```

Нужно отсортировать по 2 полям НО, так чтоб сначала выбрались все записи со статусом  `comlite`, а всё что дальше просто отсортировалось по дате.
Прошу натолкнуть на вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
Task::find()
  ->orderBy(['IF((status="comlite")=0,1,0) ASC', 'add_date ASC'])
  ->all();
```